# How can I change my browser's date for testing?

Tags: javascript, testing

Some of my DOMs depend on the current date and I use this code snippet to determine that:

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();

setComboBoxOptions($('#optionRpd0'), year    );
setComboBoxOptions($('#optionRpd1'), year - 1);
setComboBoxOptions($('#optionRpd2'), year - 2);
setComboBoxOptions($('#optionRpd3'), year - 3);
setComboBoxOptions($('#optionRpd4'), year - 4);
```

The question is, I now need to test this is working correctly. How can I change the value being returned by `d.getFullYear()`?

Comment: Really? You just pass a date to `new Date`, for instance `var d = new Date(2015, 3, 3);`

Comment: Also, the browser uses the system time, so just change the time in the OS if you really feel a need to test that ?

Comment: @adeneo - That's a good solution. Unfortunately doesn't work for me, as I don't have admin privs, but a good solution nonetheless.

Comment: you can create a new global Date() function that returns whatever you want, including a certain or offset date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setFullYear` method.

```
d.setFullYear(2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is 'year' is coming in the form which is not number 
the best way to address these issues is to convert the year into number (**using parseInt**)and then subtract from it

**parseInt(year)-1**

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();
var year = d.getFullYear();

setComboBoxOptions($('#optionRpd0'), parseInt(year)    );
setComboBoxOptions($('#optionRpd1'), parseInt(year) - 1);
setComboBoxOptions($('#optionRpd2'), parseInt(year) - 2);
setComboBoxOptions($('#optionRpd3'), parseInt(year) - 3);
setComboBoxOptions($('#optionRpd4'), parseInt(year) - 4);
```

Comment: Firstly, this doesn't really answer the question. Secondly, never call `parseInt()` without passing the `radix` parameter, otherwise you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: i guess this works too , with radix as parameter is better way to do things , but it will works with parseInt()  too .